# Extra content at the end of the document in XML

Tags: xml

I'm encountering this error message 'Extra content at the end of the document in XML' in my browser when displaying this XML document, what should I do to fix the problem?

```
<personnel>
    <person id='demo'>
        <firstname> Ali </firstname>
        <lastname> Adam </lastname>
        <title> Doc</title>
        <sector> R&D </sector>
    </person>
</personnel>
<personnel>
    <person id='demo2'>
        <firstname> Salem</firstname>
        <lastname> Tarek </lastname>
        <title> Dev </title>
        <sector> Tech </sector>
    </person>
</personnel>
```

Comment: Is that your whole document? Because it has no root tag. There should be a single tag at root level that would contain your two `<personnel>`  tags. If your error mentions a line and column I assume they correspond to the start of the second `<personnel>` tag.

Comment: If you do have a root tag, check for control characters. If you're on linux use `cat -A` and learn about the caret notation it uses to display them (look in particular for `^M`). If you're on windows check if your editor as an option to display all characters, often represented by the ¶ symbol

Comment: XML documents must have a single root element.  As @Aaron has said, yours does not; it has two.  Either wrap both in a single element, or delete all but the first element.   Your case as posted is #2 in the answer to the duplicate Q/A, but watch out for the other cases if your problem persists.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. Indeed, the problem was solved by wrapping the document inside one single root element.